# I am looking for a text editor allowing to save and edit a list of search and replace expressions (search in multiple files, a plus)

Tags: linux, text-editor, gui, text-search, regex

I am looking for a text editor for linux (I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) that is able to save, let me edit and choose among a list of search and replace list. I have looked around and cannot find what I am looking for.

I am currently using a combination of [Altsearch and replace](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer), an extension of Libreoffice, plus the search and replace window of Libreoffice because not all expressions work in the above extension (which allows to use a list of searches though). This is one reason why I am looking for a text editor.

Another one is that the books and articles initially edited in Libreoffice are finally made into md and latex documents.

I am familiar with BBedit which would be perfect, but it is only for Mac.

So, I would like to be able to use a text editor that:

Has a GUI interface and allows

- using regex
- storing a list of search and replace expressions with titles
- editing this list easily selecting which search and replace expression is used at a given time
- searching and replacing in multiple files (this would be a plus)
- Is multiplatform (Mac, Windows, Linux)
- Is free and opensource (although if a good paid editor exists, I am open to it)

I hope that somebody can help.

Comment: And did you checked atom or does it not fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) on Windows for a while now for my text editing needs.  They apparently have Linux & Macintosh versions as well.  It supports find-replace across open files, with regular-expressions even.  It is free on all platforms, but only [kindof-sortof-notreally open source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4288/is-microsoft-vs-code-really-open-source).  It also has a wide range of plugins & extensions which you can apply to your specific development scenario, and syntax highlighting for many text-formats (json, xml, C++, python, etc).

This plugin looks like it adds the capability to do what you are asking: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules

Comment: Thanks @GarThor, VSCode looks good, but I was not able to find an extension that stores multiple regex and allows their use selectively.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed the requirement where you need to store the regex.  I'm not sure I know of an editor which lets you do that.  I think some regex testers online will let you do that though?  Maybe store the regex in a plain text/csv/xls file along with notes, and copy-paste them when you need them?

It does have the capability to let you write scripts for common tasks as well.  That might be a good option?

Comment: Hi @GarThor, although I cannot rule out the solution you propose, having to use dozens of regex to clean up texts, I still think that the storage function is a must for me. Presently I am still using LO and AltSearch extension which is multiplatform and albeit not suitable for text editing, it can be used for that too and stores the regex. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was going to suggest attempting to define a custom task for the thing you are trying to do, but I found this extension which already does what you want, and seems pretty easy to configure.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules

According to the documentation it was inspired by the sublime text plugin RegReplace, so if you like sublime that might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Check for **atom editor**, a lot of addons `https://atom.io` and you can write your on adds and scripts, it's a `hackable editor`and it is **free and open source**.

If you can't install over the `standard` or `non free` `packages`, try to install over `snap`.

Use it on OS X, Windows, or Linux.

Check this for ubuntu install:

[How to Install Atom Text Editor on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-atom-text-editor-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

[Search and Replace with RegEx components in Atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220444/search-and-replace-with-regex-components-in-atom-editor)

Comment: Thanks @Blockchain Office, I could install Atom, but the only package that approximates what I am looking for (https://github.com/pgilfernandez/multiple-find-replace) does not work as I need it to unfortunately, and writing my own adds and scripts is beyond my capacities, but thanks for the trouble!